# Dirac delta "function" $\delta(x+y)$

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

What is the proper definition of the distribution underneath this notation?

Since "$x\mapsto \delta(x)$" is define with respect to the distribution $\delta$ such that $$\langle \delta, f \rangle = f(0) $$
is "$(x,y)\mapsto \delta(x+y)$" define with respect to the distribution $T$ such that (with $g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$) 
$$\langle T, g \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x,-x) d x  \ ?$$

**Attempt :**

If I try to use "$(x,y)\mapsto \delta(x+y)$" to define my distribution as if it were a true function (and assuming Fubini is working for the sake of the guess), I would have
$$\hspace{-50pt}
\begin{align*}
 \langle T, g \rangle & =\iint g(x,y)\delta(x+y)dx dy \\
& = \int \bigg(\int g(x,y)\delta(x+y) dx\bigg) dy \\
& = \int   g(-y,y)  dy   \tag{$= \int   g(x,-x)  dx$, with $x=-y$}
\end{align*}
$$
(since $\int g(x,y)\delta(x+y) dx=\langle \delta_{-y}, g(.,y) \rangle=g(-y,y)\ $).

**Generalisation**

If $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the distribution $\delta_h$ denoted by $\delta(h(x))$ is define by 
$$ \langle \delta_h, g \rangle = \int_{\{h(y)=0\}} g(x) d x, \quad  g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) $$

Comment: @XanderHenderson see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657870/an-identity-on-deltaxy ; people use $\delta(x+y)$ as a "function" of 2 variables, so it implies a distribution over test-functions define on $\mathbb{R}^2$, yes!

Comment: @XanderHenderson see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705991/dirac-delta-function-integral

Comment: Your hunch is pretty much correct. The delta only kills one of the two integrals and enforces the relationship between x and y.

Comment: 2 votes to close this question? What is the problem with it? I swear, it is not an homework... Don't you think it is interesting to understand how things are properly define?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: what do you think of my edit? Will you help me to remove this pitiful "-1" in front of my sincere question?

Comment: @Spencer : are you ok with the generalization stated in my edit?

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close, but the only negative comment is with regards to the clarity of the question. I admit that I also had trouble understanding your question, even though I had already seen your comment on the other question which motivated this one.

Comment: With regards to your generalization it seems to be missing an important property $\delta(g(x)) =\sum \delta(x-x_i) / |g'(x_i)|$

Comment: I'm no mathematician so I may be misunderstanding your notation.

Comment: @Spencer Thank you for this remark, I will look closely to that point

Comment: I originally voted to close the question because it consisted of about four lines, none of which were clear.  The edits are a vast improvement, and I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ok :)

Comment: As Spencer said, your generalization is nonstandard and suboptimal since it does not play nicely with the substitution rule. His formula gives the correct answer if $n=1$ and $h'(x_i)\neq 0$ whenever $h(x_i)\neq 0$. More generally, one can define $\delta_h$ whenever $0$ is a regular value of $h$, i.e. $D_xh$ is surjective whenever $h(x) = 0$. In this case it is given by something like $\langle \delta_h,g\rangle = \int_{h = 0} \frac{g(x)}{\|D_x h\|}\mathrm dx$. You can find some references here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback+of+a+distribution

Comment: @Bertram thank you so much for those references. I'll update my "Generalization" proposal as soon as I will get better this points.

Comment: I like very much [this Ron Gordon's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56998/8157) on the formula $\delta(g(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to define $T(x,y)=\delta(x+y)$ as an element of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ one can use at least three different methods.

**Method 1:**

As in the OP, after the formal manipulations one can use the last line as a definition. Namely, for any smooth compactly supported function $g(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, one sets
$$
\langle T, g\rangle:=\int g(x,-x)\ dx\ .
$$

**Method 2:**

Take the tensor product of the two distribution in one variable given by $\delta(x)$ and the constant function (of $y$) equal to one.
This gives $S=\delta\otimes 1\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which one can write formally as
$$
S(x,y)=\delta(x)\ .
$$ 
Then use the definition of pull-backs of distributions by diffeomorphisms in order to define $T(x,y):=S(x+y,y)$.

**Method 3:**

For $n\ge 1$ let
$$
\phi_n(x)=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{n^2 x^2}{2}}
$$
and
$$
T_n(x,y)=\phi_n(x+y)\ .
$$
The function $T_n$ is locally integrable and thus defines a distribution $T_n$. Then let $T:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n$ in the (strong) topology of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

All these methods are equivalent, i.e., produce the same distribution $T$. For the generalization with $h$, I recommend trying Method 3 first (in order to realize that this requires some "niceness" hypotheses on $h$).